# NavLink active on same link for multiple URLs in React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page with multiple tabs (child). I also change the URL for each tab, but I'm still on the parent page, just changing the URL for the tab.

the problem is that I can't keep the parent page NavLink active when I click on the tab 'cause it changes the URL, but I want to keep that Active on the Tabs URL.

How to do this?

import React        from 'react';
import { NavLink }  from 'react-router-dom';

```
export default () => {


    return (
        <>
        <nav className='Navigation'>
            <ul className={`Navigation__list ${hide}`}>
                <li className='Navigation__list-item'> 
                   <NavLink to="/events" >Events</NavLink> 
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <Tabs />
       </>

    );
}
```

// Tabs Component As Child

```
    export default function Tabs () => (
                <ul className="events__tab">
                    <li> <NavLink to="/events"> All Events </NavLink> </li>
                    <li> <NavLink to="/myevents"> My Events </NavLink> </li>   
                </ul>
)
```

Thanks for your Support in Advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you have to do is to Write a condition inside `isActive` in `NavLink`, if the current page URL matches with defined URLs, return `true` otherwise `false`. use the function inside `isActive`, if it return true, you'll get active Link.. 
Example:

```
    isActive={ () => ['/example', '/exampl2'].inclues(currentPageUrl) }
```

if the current URL matches in the Above Array, your NavLink will be Active as long as URL doesn't match.
for finding the Current Page URL use the `useLocation()` hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// Active the Link on two URLs

export default () => {

    // extract pathname from location
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    return (
        <li className='Navigation__list-item'> 
            <NavLink 
                to="/events" 
                isActive={() => ['/events', '/myevents'].includes(pathname)} >
                Events 
            </NavLink> 
        </li>
    );
};
```

Comment: One year later, is still an helpful solution.
Thanks!

Comment: @Daniele am happy you found it helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add end attr in navLink

```
 export default function Tabs () => (
            <ul className="events__tab">
                <li> <NavLink end to="/events"> All Events </NavLink> </li> // which on same link
                <li> <NavLink to="/myevents"> My Events </NavLink> </li>   
            </ul>
)
```