# react router v6 "NavLink" active with multiple links

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In react router V6 I use the following:

```
        <NavLink
            className={({ isActive,  }) =>
                concatClasses(classes, 'container', isActive ? 'container--active' : null)
            }
            to={props.route}
        >
            <EDSvg className={classes['container__icon']} name={props.iconName} />
            <span className={classes['container__text']}>{props.text}</span>
        </NavLink>
```

If, for example, `props.route` is "blabla" then It will match.
I have a scenario where I want it to be active for both "blabla" and "lala"

Is it possible>?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62228742/11095009

Comment: @S.Marx There is no `isActive` no longer in v6